# DynamoDB tables per customer considering DynamoDB's advanced recovery abilities

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am deciding whether or not I have tables per a customer, or a customer shares a table with everybody else. Creating a table for every customer seems problematic, as it is just another thing to manage.

But then I thought about backing up the database. There could be a situation where a customer does not have strong IT security, or even a disgruntled employee, and that this person goes and deletes a whole bunch of crucial data of the customer.

In this scenario if all the customers are on the same table, one couldn't just restore from a DynamoDB snapshot 2 days ago for instance, as then all other customers would lose the past 2 days of data. Before cloud this really wasn't such a prevalent consideration IMO because backups were not as straight forward offering such functionality to your customers who are not tier 1 businesses wasn't really on the table.

But this functionality could be a huge selling point for my SAAS application so now I am thinking it will be worth the hassle for me to have table per customer. Is this the right line of thinking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a good line of thinking to me. A couple of other things you might want to consider:

- Having all customer data in one table will probably be cheaper as you can distribute RCUs and WCUs more efficiently. From your customer point of view this might be good or bad because one customer can spend any customers RCUs/WCUs (if you want to think about like that). If you split customer data into separate tables your can provision them independently.
- Fine grained security isn't great in DynamoDB. You can only really implement row (item) level security if the partition key of the table is an Amazon uid. If this isn't possible you are relying on application code to protect customer data. Splitting customer data into separate tables will improve security (if you cant use item level security).

On to your question. DynamoDB backups don't actually have to be restored into the same table. So potentially you could have all your customer data in one table which is backed up. If one customer requests a restore you could load the data into a new table, sync their data into the live table and then remove the restore table. This wouldn't necessarily be easy, but you could give it a try. Also you could be paying for all the RCUs/WCUs as you perform your sync - a cost you don't incur on a restore.

Hope some of that is useful.

Comment: This helped allot! I didn't think about RCUs/WCUs, also that merging tables could keep the backups going.

Answer (score 1):

Separate tables:

- Max number of tables. It's probably a soft limit but you'd have to contact support rather often - extra overhead for you because they prefer to raise limits in small (reasonable) bits.
- A lot more things to manage, secure, monitor etc.
- There's probably a lot more RCU and WCU waste.

---

Just throwing another idea up in the air, haven't tried it or considered every pro and con.

Pick up all the write ops with Lambda and write them to backup table(s). Use TTL (for how long can users restore their stuff) to delete old entries for free. You could even modify TTL per costumer basis if you e.g provide longer backups for different price classes of your service.

You need a good schema to avoid hot keys.

```
customer-id (partition ID) | time-of-operation#uuid (sort key) | data, source table etc
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

E.g this example might be problematic if some of your costumers are a lot more active than others.

Possible solution: use **known** range of `int-s` to suffix IDs, e.g `customer-id#1`, `customer-id#2` `... customer-id#100` etc. This will spread the writes and your app knows the range - able to query.

Anyway, this is just a quick and dirty example off the top of my head.

---

Few pros and cons that come to my mind:

- *Probably* more expensive unless separate tables have big RCU/WCU headroom.
- Restoring from regular backup might be a huge headache, e.g which items to sync?
- This is very cranual, users can pick any moment in your TTL range to restore.
- Restore specific items, revert specific ops w/ very low cost if your schema allows it.
- Could use that backup data to e.g show history of items in front-end.